# Historical perspectives on CAT(0) spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, ho.history-overview, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

Does there exist a survey on the early developments of CAT(k) spaces, with the first motivations and the first problems considered? I looked at Bridson and Haefliger's book *On metric spaces of non-positive curvature*, and I only found the following references:

- Rinow, *Die innere Geometrie der metrischen Raüme*. On the period to 1960. However, the book is written in German.
- Two papers of Alexandrov, written in Russian.
- Gromov, *Hyperbolic groups*. Where the term CAT(k) is coined. However, I did not see historical considerations nor references.

The first point is that I do not read German nor Russian... Anyway, these references are old and necessarily are far from being exhaustive nowadays. Do you know if there exists a good reference on the subject?

Comment: I cannot look this up right now, but I think this book may be useful: Burago, Dmitri, Yuri Burago, and Sergei Ivanov. *A course in metric geometry*. Vol. 33. Providence: American Mathematical Society, 2001.

Comment: Burago, Burago and Ivanov is a beautiful book, but I don't think it has much historical information.

Comment: You can look at Alexandrov, A. D., Selected works. Part I. Selected scientific papers. Translated from the Russian by P. S. V. Naidu. Edited and with a preface by Yu. G. Reshetnyak and S. S. Kutateladze. Classics of Soviet Mathematics, 4. Gordon and Breach Publishers, Amsterdam, 1996.

Comment: Take a look at various papers and books of [Anton Petrunin](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/papers/).